# Plot several continuous variables according to the nominal values of two variables using Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I would like to create a figure that shows how much money people earned in a game (continuous variable) as a function of the categorical values of three other variables. The first variable is whether people were included or excluded prior to the Money game, the second variable is whether people knew their decision-making partner and the last is the round of the game (participants played 5 rounds with a known co-player and 5 rounds with an unknown co-player). I know how to do draw violin plots as a function of the values of two categorical variables using FacetGrid (see below) but I did not manage to add another layer to it.

```
g= sns.FacetGrid(df_long, col = 'XP_Social_Condition', size=5, aspect=1)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'DM partner', 'Money', palette = col_talk)
```

I have created  two dataframe versions: my initial one and a melted one (see image below). I have also tried to create two plots together using `f, (ax_l, ax_r) =` but this does not seem to take `FacetGrid` plots as plots within the plot... You can see below links to see the data and the kind of plot I would like to use as a subplot - one showing a known player and one showing the unknown player. I am happy to share the data if it would help.

I have now tried the solution proposed

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(melted_df, hue='DM partner', col='XP_Social_Condition')
grid.map(sns.violinplot, 'Round', 'Money')
```

But it still does not work. This shows the plot shown below, with the third hue variable not showing well the different conditions.

[here is the new figure I get - almost there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r6wY.png)

[data - original and melted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM3O7.png)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I just noticed the title and content of this post don't agree. Several continuous variables against two nominal ones, vs. one continuous against three categorical...

Comment: Yes, you are right @Peter. We can think of the display I am looking for in two ways: The money rounds are 5 continuous variables and they could be plotted against two categorical variables (social exclusion and player). OR if one uses a melted frame, money earned is the only continuous variable that then needs to be plotted against three categorical variable (social exclusion, player and rounds). Sorry about this and I hope it makes sense...

Comment: Ah, right. The round is not continuous (i.e. you can't be in round 1.2); it's categorical (ordinal to be precise).

Comment: Maybe check out the [tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html#drawing-multi-panel-categorical-plots) on categorical plots?

Comment: thank you @mwaskom, I checked this but none of the examples showed one continuous variables plotted according to three categorical variables...

Comment: That is exactly what is shown in the third and fourth examples.

Comment: No it is not the same - sorry my query may be confusing: I want either to plot 5 continuous variables according to the values of two categorical variables OR to plot 1 continuous variable according to three categorical variables. Both would work for me and the choice depends on the format of my dataframe (melted or not). In the tutorial that you suggest, they show a single continuous variable according to two categorical variable.. Which is not what I need...

Comment: @Peter, in the non melted version of the data-frame the 5 variables are continuous because they show the amount of money earned in 5 rounds. In the melted dataframe: rounds became an ordinal variable indeed (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5) and the value variable shows the earning across the 5 rounds.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you want to create one plot of continuous data depending on three different categorical variables?

I think what you're looking for is:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(melted_df, col='XP_Social_Condition')
grid.map(sns.violinplot, 'Round', 'Money', 'DM partner').add_legend()
```

The `col` results in two plots, one for each value of `XP_Social_Condition`. The three values passed to `grid.map` split the data so `'Round'` becomes the x-axis, `'money'` the y-axis and `'DM partner'` the color. You can play around and swap the values `'DM_partner'`, `'XP_Social_Condition'` and `'Round'`.

The result should now look something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2rd0md9at09dql/violinplot2.png?dl=0) or [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/inm6cipt17btkwi/violinplot.png?dl=0) (`'Round'` and `'DM Partner'` swapped).

Comment: Hello @Peter, thank you for your help! Unfortunately this is not working on my side. I receive an error message: "Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric."

Comment: Are the money values actually stored as floats? I would expect this exception when the money values are stored as strings.

Comment: yes you were right, I changed the type to float and I can now see a plot! However the plot does not show the player data. I get two plots next to each other, one showing the five rounds of money earned in the inclusion condition and the other showing the five rounds of money earned in the exclusion condition. The problem seems to be that the player conditions are shown on top of each other instead of being shown separately/next to each other. Sorry I cannot send an image to show you...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I thought that was exactly what you meant. Could you somehow draw the actual plot you would like to have, because I don't follow...

Comment: Hi Peter, I have updated my question so that you can see the graph that your programme created. I really appreciate your help... M

Comment: @MarieJ Your picture really helped understanding what went wrong. The violin plot does not play nice with `hue`, but has it's own built-in way of switching colors. I updated my answer.